# A generic error occurred in GDI+ (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, picturebox, gdi

A Generic error occurred in GDI+ (Vb.NET)

Code for Save Button:

```
If MessageBox.Show("Before continuing, make sure you profile picture doesn't contain any material that is sensitive or controversial. Do you want to change your profile picture?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = vbYes Then

    If PbProfilePicture.Image IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ImagePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\frmUserProfilePictures"
        Dim NewFile As String = LblUniqueID_MainMenu.Text & ".jpg"

        PbProfilePicture.Image.Save(ImagePath & "\" & NewFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        MessageBox.Show("Your profile picture has been saved!", "Profile picture changed successfully", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Modify.CheckProfilePicture_IfExist(LblUniqueID_MainMenu.Text)
        BtnSaveImage.Visible = False
        BtnChangePicture.Text = "Change"
        BtnChangePicture.BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise
    End If
End If
```

Code for the open dialog (change pic):

```
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim DuplicateImage As Image

    Dim UserImage As String = UniqueID & ".jpg"
    Dim ImagePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\frmUserProfilePictures\"

    If frmUserMainMenu.BtnChangePicture.Text = "Change" Then
        With OFD
            .CheckFileExists = True
            .ShowReadOnly = False
            .Filter = "JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|PNG files (*.png)|*.png|ALL files (*.*)|*.*"
            .FilterIndex = 1

            If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                DuplicateImage = Image.FromFile(.FileName)
                Picture.Image = DuplicateImage

                frmUserMainMenu.BtnChangePicture.BackColor = Color.IndianRed
                frmUserMainMenu.BtnChangePicture.Text = "Remove"
                frmUserMainMenu.BtnSaveImage.Visible = True
            Else
                If System.IO.File.Exists(ImagePath & UserImage) Then
                    frmUserMainMenu.PbProfilePicture.Image = Image.FromFile(ImagePath & UserImage)
                End If
                .Dispose()
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

I have a system that has a feature of changing profile pictures but if i save the profile picture it always has an error called A Generic error occurred in GDI+ (Vb.NET)

Comment: The first thing you have to change is this: `DuplicateImage = Image.FromFile(.FileName)`. Replace with `DuplicateImage = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(.FileName)), true, false)`. The same goes for `PbProfilePicture.Image`

Comment: Adding to Jimi's comment, when you use [Image.FromFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) it says in the REMARKS that "The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.". When you change to Jimi's code the file does not get locked...

Comment: @Jimi what should I change on the `PbProfilePicture.Image` exactly?

Comment: Basically anywhere you're using `Image.FromFile()` you need to replace it with `Image.FromStream()` as demonstrated in Jimi's comment.

Comment: @Idle_Mind , so like... `PbProfilePicture.Image = Image.FromStream(???)`. Is there anything should I add or edit in the in order to work? Sorry for the stupid question it's my first time doing this feature so yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the following code, just as Jimi's example.

`PbProfilePicture.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath & UserImage))`

Replace the ***Image.FromFile(*** ImagePath & UserImage ***)*** part with ***Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(*** ImagePath & UserImage ***))***